# Unsuccessful login with external provider

Tags: federated-authentication, owin

I have setup federated authentication for my Sitecore 9.1 website, to allow **end users** to login using Azure B2C AD. Our website is following Helix architecture.

This is my code:

Portal.Website.config:

```
<federatedAuthentication>
  <identityProvidersPerSites>
    <mapEntry name="portal" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>portal</site>
      </sites>
      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='AzureAdB2C']"/>
      </identityProviders>
      <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
        <param desc="isPersistentUser">false</param>
      </externalUserBuilder>
    </mapEntry>
  </identityProvidersPerSites>
</federatedAuthentication>
```

Configuration for Helix module that implements Azure B2C logic (Feature.AzureB2C.config):

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Feature.AzureAdB2C.Models.Routes.RegisterAuthRoute, Feature.AzureAdB2C"
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" resolve="true" />
      </initialize>
      <owin.identityProviders>
        <!--This is the custom processor that gets executed when azure AD posts the token to Sitecore-->
        <processor type="Feature.AzureAdB2C.AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor, Feature.AzureAdB2C" resolve="true" />
      </owin.identityProviders>
    </pipelines>
    <federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <!--Provider mappings to sites-->
      <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
      </identityProvidersPerSites>

      <!--Definitions of providers-->
      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <!--Facebook provider-->
        <identityProvider id="AzureAdB2C" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <param desc="name">AzureAdB2C</param>
          <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
          <caption>AzureAdB2C</caption>
          <domain>portal</domain>
          <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
            <transformation name="Name Identifier Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
          </transformations>
        </identityProvider>
      </identityProviders>

      <!--List of all shared transformations-->
      <sharedTransformations>
      </sharedTransformations>

      <!--Property mappings initializer-->
      <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
        <!--List of property mappings
                    Note that all mappings from the list will be applied to each providers-->
        <maps hint="list">
          <!--The mapping sets the Email property of the user profile from emailaddress claim-->
          <map name="email claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
            <data hint="raw:AddData">
              <!--claim name-->
              <source name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" />
              <!--property name-->
              <target name="Email" />
            </data>
          </map>
        </maps>
      </propertyInitializer>

    </federatedAuthentication>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Route registration:

```
public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("AuthRoute", "auth/sso/{action}", new
    {
        controller = "Sso"
    });

    SsoLogger.Info("RegisterAuthRoute - Registered route: auth/sso/{action}");

    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("LoginContentRoute", "api/content/{action}", new
    {
        controller = "Content"
    });

    SsoLogger.Info("LoginContentRoute - Registered route: api/login/{action}");
}
```

IdentityProviderProcessor implementation:

```
public class AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor : IdentityProvidersProcessor
{
    private readonly ISsoConfigurationRepository _ssoConfigurationRepository;
    private readonly string _aadInstance = SsoConfiguration.AadInstance;
    private readonly string _tenant = SsoConfiguration.Tenant;
    private readonly string _ssoAuthenticationRootPath = SsoConfiguration.Routes.RootPath;

    protected override string IdentityProviderName => "AzureAdB2C";

    public AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor(
        FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, ICookieManager cookieManager,
        BaseSettings settings) : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, cookieManager, settings)
    {
        _ssoConfigurationRepository = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISsoConfigurationRepository>();
    }

    protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

        var identityProvider = GetIdentityProvider();
        var authenticationType = GetAuthenticationType();

        args.App.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        args.App.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            CookieName = SsoConfiguration.SsoCookieName,
            CookiePath = _ssoAuthenticationRootPath, // Scope cookies to the authentication root path in order to avoid having the cookie included in every normal request.
            TicketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(new MachineKeyProtector()) // In order to be able to decrypt the authentication ticket stored in the cookie later on, we use protection based on the machine key.
        });
        List<B2CConfig> ssoSettings = _ssoConfigurationRepository.GetAllSettings();

        foreach (var config in ssoSettings)
        {
            args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromSiteConfig(config));
        }
    }

    private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromSiteConfig(B2CConfig config)
    {
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions();
        var identityProvider = GetIdentityProvider();

        // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
        // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
        options.MetadataAddress = string.Format(_aadInstance, _tenant, config.Policy);
        options.AuthenticationType = config.Policy;

        options.RedirectUri = config.AzureReplyUri;
        options.PostLogoutRedirectUri = config.RedirectAfterLogoutUri;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "emails"
        };

        options.Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
            {
                return Task.FromResult(notification.ProtocolMessage.UiLocales = config.UiLocale ?? string.Empty);
            },
            SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
            {
                notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("idp", "azureadb2c"));

                // transform all claims
                ClaimsIdentity identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                foreach (Transformation current in identityProvider.Transformations)
                {
                    current.Transform(identity, new TransformationContext(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };

        // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
        options.ClientId = config.ClientId;
        //http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest
        options.Scope = "openid";
        //http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authentication
        options.ResponseType = "id_token";

        return options;
    }
}
```

Example of B2CConfig class:

```
public class B2CConfig
{
    public string Policy { get; }

    public string AzureReplyUri { get; }

    public string LogoutRedirectUri { get; }

    public string ClientId { get; }

    public string UiLocale { get; }    
}
```

The login works for end users, but when I try to login to Sitecore, I receive the error message: "Error: "Unsuccessful login with external provider".

As far as I can understand from blogs and https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/252884 it is due to the fact that the "name"-claim is missing.

However, since I don't want to use my custom provider for Sitecore client login, but only want to use it for end user login on the website, I am confused as to why Sitecore throws this error? Is there somewhere I have to explicitly tell Sitecore NOT to use my custom identity provider for Sitecore client logins?

Comment: have you configured the federated auth in CM servers as well.? if you don't want the custom provider to be used for client login then i guess you can ignore this integration in CM servers.

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to get it to work locally (combined cd-cm) :)

Comment: Hi @Hos, you are getting "Unsuccessful login with external provider" error message while clicking on default "Log In" button or custom "AzureAdB2C" external authentication button?

Comment: @ArvindGehlot while clicking on default "Log in" button...which is why I am confused now

Comment: @Hos I guess, there is something in your routeing table as you register a processor Feature.AzureAdB2C.Models.Routes.RegisterAuthRoute in initialize pipeline. Please re-verify what route you have registered and whether it is impacting your default login request or not.

Comment: @ArvindGehlot I updated question with route registration - I think it looks ok?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally managed to get both Sitecore login (standard) and enduser login (Azure B2C AD) to work at the same time. I did a few changes and I am not 100% sure exactly which of them made the difference, so I will just list them and post the working code.

Changes:

- Moved the Feature.AzureB2C.config (config file for Identity provider) out of a "zFeature" folder and into a "Feature" folder
- Added service registrations for BaseAuthenticationManager, BaseTicketManager and BasePreviewManager to my config file (Feature.AzureAdB2C.config)
- Simplified IdentityProviderProcessor implementation (see below)
- Set authenticationmode in IdentityProviderProcessor

  ```
  public class AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor : IdentityProvidersProcessor
  {

      private readonly ISsoConfigurationRepository _ssoConfigurationRepository;
      private readonly string _aadInstance = SsoConfiguration.AadInstance;
      private readonly string _tenant = SsoConfiguration.Tenant;
      private readonly string _ssoAuthenticationRootPath = SsoConfiguration.Routes.RootPath;

      protected override string IdentityProviderName => "AzureAdB2C";

      public AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor(
          FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, ICookieManager cookieManager,
          BaseSettings settings) : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, cookieManager, settings)
      {
          _ssoConfigurationRepository = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISsoConfigurationRepository>();
      }

      protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
      {
          Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

          List<B2CConfig> ssoSettings = _ssoConfigurationRepository.GetAllSettings();

          foreach (var config in ssoSettings)
          {
              args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromSiteConfig(config));
          }
      }

      private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromSiteConfig(B2CConfig config)
      {
          OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions();
          var identityProvider = GetIdentityProvider();

          // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
          // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
          options.MetadataAddress = string.Format(_aadInstance, _tenant, config.Policy);
          options.AuthenticationType = GetAuthenticationType();
          options.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;
          options.RedirectUri = config.AzureReplyUri;
          options.PostLogoutRedirectUri = config.RedirectAfterLogoutUri;
          options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
          {
              NameClaimType = "emails"
          };

          options.Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
          {
              AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
              RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
              {
                  return Task.FromResult(notification.ProtocolMessage.UiLocales = config.UiLocale ?? string.Empty);
              },
              SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
              {
                  notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("idp", "azureadb2c"));

                  // transform all claims
                  ClaimsIdentity identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                  notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.ApplyClaimsTransformations(new TransformationContext(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));

                  return Task.CompletedTask;
              }
          };

          // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
          options.ClientId = config.ClientId;
          //http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest
          options.Scope = "openid";
          //http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authentication
          options.ResponseType = "id_token";

          return options;
      }
  }
  ```

Feature.AzureAdB2C.config:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Feature.AzureAdB2C.Models.Routes.RegisterAuthRoute, Feature.AzureAdB2C"
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" resolve="true" />
      </initialize>
      <owin.identityProviders>
        <!--This is the custom processor that gets executed when azure AD posts the token to Sitecore-->
        <processor type="Feature.AzureAdB2C.AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor, Feature.AzureAdB2C" resolve="true" />
      </owin.identityProviders>
    </pipelines>
    <services>
      <configurator type= "Feature.AzureAdB2C.Models.AuthenticationConfigurator, Feature.AzureAdB2C"/>
      <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseAuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.AuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                lifetime="Singleton" />
      <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseTicketManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.TicketManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                lifetime="Singleton" />
      <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BasePreviewManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Publishing.PreviewManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                lifetime="Singleton" />
    </services>
    <federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <!--Provider mappings to sites-->
      <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
      </identityProvidersPerSites>

      <!--Definitions of providers-->
      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider id="AzureAdB2C" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <param desc="name">AzureAdB2C</param>
          <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
          <caption>AzureAdB2C</caption>
          <domain>portal</domain>
          <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
            <transformation name="Name Identifier Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
          </transformations>
        </identityProvider>
      </identityProviders>

      <!--List of all shared transformations-->
      <sharedTransformations>
      </sharedTransformations>

      <!--Property mappings initializer-->
      <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      </propertyInitializer>

    </federatedAuthentication>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I hope it helps someone else!

Comment: What do you have for the Feature.AzureAdB2C.Models.AuthenticationConfigurator class ?

Comment: I'm getting following error when try to login "Error: Unsuccessful login with external provider." . Do you have any idea on the reason for that ?

Comment: AuthenticationConfigurator is just used for serviceregistration, i.e. an implementation of IServicesConfigurator (used for Dependency Injection)

Comment: Thanks.. was able to get the integration working..

Comment: @Hos am currently working an Azure B2C Login for end users , what does the route configurations do ? why is it required ?

Comment: @SitecoreNoob The route registration code can be found in my original post. It is not strictly required, however, it is what I use to trigger the authentication to AzureB2C. So when a user hits my auth route, I initiate authentication to AzureB2CAD

Comment: @Hos Thanks for your reply Hos , how to trigger Authentication to Azure B2C? , sorry new to Azure AD or Azure B2C , any blogs or articles you can point me to

Comment: @SitecoreNoob Depending on what yoy need I would checkout the Azure samples: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

Comment: Can you share your ISsoConfigurationRepository and B2CConfig files

Comment: @AbhayDhar I added the B2CConfig class. The ISsoConfigurationRepository basically creates instances of the B2CConfig class.

Comment: Thanks @Hos - I followed all your steps exactly same, then I was able to redirect user. Earlier when I was doing , the Owin redirect to Azure ADb2C was not hppening, but dont know the reason for the same, I thnk the config entries had to be followed correctly.

Comment: Hi All, I am able to authenticate using the solution provided above. After authentication, I am able to redirect to login page as well that we created but after that it redirects to "https://hostname/sitecore/service/error.aspx?error=An+error+occured". Any idea how to resolve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you happen to be logged into Sitecore, in another tab? Please retry in incognito

Comment: Hi @Hos . Not logged into sitecore. Tried in incognito, different browsers as well.

Comment: @Hos What is the value of Context.User after authentication and redirection?

Comment: @NewbieHere I am sorry, but I no longer have access to the source code. It was written at a previous job

Comment: Hi, Were you able to achieve this for Multi-site scenario. How can you get different Return URLs for different sites? I'm not getting Site context in the identity processor.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer wasn't clear on exactly the problem, I came across this in an Auth0 B2C integration and removing these from the IdentityProviderProcessor fixed it. I think these may already be getting registered by Sitecore.

```
    args.App.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    args.App.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        CookieName = SsoConfiguration.SsoCookieName,
        CookiePath = _ssoAuthenticationRootPath, // Scope cookies to the authentication root path in order to avoid having the cookie included in every normal request.
        TicketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(new MachineKeyProtector()) // In order to be able to decrypt the authentication ticket stored in the cookie later on, we use protection based on the machine key.
    });
```

Comment: It seems, CookieAuthentication is added as part of this Owin pipeline:

<processor name="CookieAuthentication" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.Initialize.CookieAuthentication, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" /> and SeDetaultSigninAsAuthenticationType is set in this pipeline:
<processor type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.Initialize.ExternalCookieAuthentication, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />

Comment: args.App.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType); This piece of code was the main culprit for me

Comment: Can you please provide your Login Action method as well?

Comment: @NewbieHere I am sorry, but I no longer have access to the source code. It was written at a previous job

Comment: @Hos Thank you for your reply.