# Login with multiple Identity Providers at the same time

Tags: federated-authentication, identity-server, owin

I've configured a custom Identity Provider based on this info:

http://blog.baslijten.com/enable-federated-authentication-and-configure-auth0-as-an-identity-provider-in-sitecore-9-0/

[Unsuccessful login with external provider](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18492/unsuccessful-login-with-external-provider)

It works and I can login. This is how it looks in my merged config.

**identityProvidersPerSites**

```
<identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites" patch:source="Foundation.Identity.config">
<!--  Defines a list of providers assigned to all sites.  -->
<mapEntry name="all sites" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
<!--
 The list of site names for which the specified identity providers will work.
               Note: the fedauth.siteNameExpander pipeline processes each site name, which gives the ability to use expressions like
               "regexp:modules_.*" or "database:web" or "domain:extranet" 
-->
<sites hint="list">
<site>regexp:.*</site>
</sites>
<identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider"/>
<externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
<IsPersistentUser>true</IsPersistentUser>
</externalUserBuilder>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry name="sites with the web database" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
<sites hint="list">
<site>database:web</site>
</sites>
<identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider"/>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry name="sites with the core and unspecified database" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config">
<sites hint="list">
<site>database:core</site>
<site>database:</site>
</sites>
<identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider" patch:source="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config">
<identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer" ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='SitecoreIdentityServer']" patch:source="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config"/>
</identityProviders>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry name="sites with extranet domain" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true" patch:source="Foundation.Identity.config">
<sites hint="list" patch:source="Foundation.Identity.config">
<site>mywebsite</site>
</sites>
<identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider" patch:source="Foundation.Identity.config">
<identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='ExternalIdentityProvider']"/>
</identityProviders>
<externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true" patch:source="Foundation.Identity.config">
<IsPersistentUser>true</IsPersistentUser>
</externalUserBuilder>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry name="admin site" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
<sites hint="list">
<site>admin</site>
</sites>
<identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider"/>
</mapEntry>
</identityProvidersPerSites>
```

**identityProviders**

```
<identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
<identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.IdentityServerProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config">
<caption>Go to login</caption>
<domain>sitecore</domain>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<triggerExternalSignOut>true</triggerExternalSignOut>
<transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
<transformation name="apply additional claims" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Transformations.ApplyAdditionalClaims, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" resolve="true"/>
<transformation name="name to long name" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
<sources hint="raw:AddSource">
<claim name="name"/>
</sources>
<targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
<claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"/>
</targets>
<keepSource>true</keepSource>
</transformation>
<transformation name="role to long role" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
<sources hint="raw:AddSource">
<claim name="role"/>
</sources>
<targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
<claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"/>
</targets>
<keepSource>false</keepSource>
</transformation>
<transformation name="set ShadowUser" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
<sources hint="raw:AddSource">
<claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider" value="local"/>
</sources>
<targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
<claim name="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/shadowuser" value="true"/>
</targets>
<keepSource>true</keepSource>
</transformation>
<transformation name="use exp claim for authentication cookie expiration" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
<sources hint="raw:AddSource">
<claim name="exp"/>
</sources>
<targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
<claim name="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/cookieExp"/>
</targets>
<keepSource>true</keepSource>
</transformation>
<transformation name="remove local role claims" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Transformations.RemoveLocalRoles, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer"/>
<transformation name="adjust NameIdentifier claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Transformations.AdjustNameIdentifierClaim, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" resolve="true"/>
</transformations>
</identityProvider>
<identityProvider id="ExternalIdentityProvider" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" patch:source="Foundation.Identity.config">
<param desc="name">$(id)</param>
<param type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" desc="domainManager" resolve="true"/>
<caption>Log in with OpenId Connect</caption>
<icon>
/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/bas.png
</icon>
<domain>extranet</domain>
<transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
<transformation name="Idp Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"/>
</transformations>
</identityProvider>
</identityProviders>
```

The problem is that I can't login on both these Identity Providers at the same time. If I login into the backoffice with the SitecoreIdentityServer provider the ".AspNet.Cookies" cookie is set. When I login in the ExternalIdentityProvider the same ".AspNet.Cookies" cookie is set.

I want to be able to login in Sitecore with SitecoreIdentityServer and the frontend with ExternalIdentityProvider at the same time. So somehow I need to make sure they each have a unique cookie and not ".AspNet.Cookies". I found these docs: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/using-federated-authentication-with-sitecore.html#idm45839230508336. It says the cookie is build like this: ".Asp." + AuthenticationType + AuthenticationSource. Does anyone know where in my Identity Provider I need to set this? I tried to create my own CookieAuthentication and use SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType, but it keeps using the same cookie.

Answer (score 4):

using different domains for front- and backend is the most simple one. Cookies won't be shared between those domains.

Comment: Hi Bas. As you can see in the identityProviders XML I'm already using the Sitecore domain for SitecoreIdentityServer and the extranet for ExternalIdentityProvider. They still override the same cookie.

Comment: I think he means a different host name, so your cookies are not shared between sites. That is the most common way of setting this up. Also, I will often use a different browser or open an incognito window.

Comment: Hi Richard. I want to login into Sitecore and preview the website. Than in preview I want to do another login with the frontend Identity Provider. So I can't use different browsers.

Comment: oeh, that's a different usecase and I don't think that would be a very feasible approach. Don't think that his is a best practice as the preview mode behaves "differently". what would you like to test out?