# Integrate Azure ADB2C with Sitecore 9.3 CD (content delivery)

Tags: identity-server, openid-connect

I've been reading a lots of references (sitecore doc/blog posts etc) on integrating **CM** with Azure AD B2C sub providers.

However, I've not been able to locate the reliable resource on how we can integrate our **CD** instance with Azure ADB2C or any other Identity Providers.

Appreciate if you can share your experience on :

1. Steps for integrating CD with Azure ADB2C
2. Need to create virtual users?
3. How is the integration different between CMS vs CD?

Thanks.

Comment: This is related to https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18492/unsuccessful-login-with-external-provider

Comment: For CD the approach will be to use custom controller with pipeline code for ADB2C configuration

Comment: the answer from Julius and the code in that question has a lot you can use directly and start integration

Answer (score 1):

The below is based on my experience of integrating Azure ADb2C with Sitecore on CD

1. Steps for integrating CD with Azure ADB2C

   *The steps for Integration are available on a lot of answers here on SSE. Many answers like [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18492/unsuccessful-login-with-external-provider) are complete and provide all the code for the integration*
2. Need to create virtual users?

   *Yes , if you want to maintain sessions and show/hide pages or functionality*
3. How is the integration different between CMS vs CD?

   *In CMS , you need to create a subprovider on Sitecore Identity Server (.Net Core) , but the underlying approach is same for both CM and CD i.e federated authentication*

Comment: Thanks Abhay,  so difference in cms vs cd implementation is that CD doesn't use Identify Server?

Comment: yes, but its based on implementation , I belive you can configure Sitecore Ids for CD nodes as well