# Single Sign On between Sitecore 9 Application and Microsoft Dynamics Portal With Azure AD B2C

Tags: authentication, federated-authentication, azure-ad

Our application is currently on `Sitecore 9.0.2`

There are two parts to our Application, one is the Sitecore application, the other part is a `Microsoft Dynamics Portal Application`

We have a requirement to authenticate and single sign-on end-users between these two applications (authenticate **end user only **, not Sitecore client)

we intend to use `Azure AD B2C` to achieve this functionality

I understand that Sitecore 9.0.2 can be configured to Authenticate users from Azure AD or Azure B2C, Will single sign-on work in this case?

If Yes, any pointers on how this functionality can be achieved?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18404/azure-ad-b2c-login-for-endusers/