# Implement SSO for Sitecore websites

Tags: sso

I have a requirement where I have to implement SSO for 4 websites. All the four websites have different domain ex. `abc.com` , `xyz.com` etc. All the websites are in the same sitecore instance. Now if the user is logged into `abc.com` then if he goes to `xyz.com`, he should be automatically logged in.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: This seems to be related to this one here, https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18404/azure-ad-b2c-login-for-endusers Does the answer for this help?

Answer (score -1):

Please create user with default domain. It will handle everything. if you have specific domain make sure you will uncheck the Locally Manage from domain manager. Let me know if it's not working for you.

Comment: if I use one domain for all the websites then same user will be able to login to all the websites but they have to login to websites separately. if user is logged in to abc.com then he will not be automatically logged in to xyz.com